# Configurable product options to use in a loop

Tags: configurable-product

For a given configurable product is it possible to loop over the available product options outputing the option value and price?

For example:

```
foreach($configurableProduct->getOptions() as $option) {
    $price = $option->getPrice();
    $value = $option->getValue();
    $label = $option->getLabel();
}
```

This obviously doesnt work but is there anything similar in the codebase that can be used to get these values?

Comment: By options do you mean the simple products related to configs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code snippet:

```
    $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
        ->getConfigurableAttributes($product);

    $options = array();
    $store   = Mage::app()->getStore();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $prices = $attribute->getPrices();
        if (is_array($prices)) {
            foreach ($prices as $value) {
                $price    = $value['pricing_value'];
                $oldPrice = $value['pricing_value'];
                if ($value['is_percent'] && $price) {
                    $price    = $product->getFinalPrice() * $price / 100;
                    $oldPrice = $product->getPrice() * $price / 100;
                }
                $price    = $store->roundPrice($store->convertPrice($price));
                $oldPrice = $store->roundPrice($store->convertPrice($oldPrice));

                $options[] = array(
                    'value'    => $value['value_index'],
                    'label'    => $value['label'],
                    'price'    => $price,
                    'oldPrice' => $oldPrice
                );
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($options);
```